# Cassandra Nodetool netstats. What exactly am i monitoring?

Tags: cassandra, monitoring, datastax, cassandra-2.0, nosql

Can anyone please let me know what to look/monitor in nodetool netstats command and its thresholds.

when we say we monitor the  number of active, pending, and completed commands and responses,  what should the threshold be? I was reading a blog and they told the thresholds are 5 and 10. I am having trouble understanding is it 5 pending commands or 5% of pending commands or a ratio between pending and active commands.

Sorry if this is silly. I am new to Cassandra.

Answer (score -1):

The numbers you see in the netstats output are actual counts. See this doc link:

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsNetstats.html

Could you elaborate on what you mean by thresholds, where are you seeing this, or what blog are you referring to?